# Work out and set date

Tags: c#, vb.net, date

Ok, say a user buys a 6 month subscription to my online app. Using c# or vb.net, How would I work out what the expiry date should be to be inserted into the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime expirationDate = todaysDate.AddMonths(6);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`DateTime.AddMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) method to create a new `DateTime` instance, adding 6 months to [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) (or maybe add six months and one day to [`DateTime.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) if you want the subscription to end at midnight or you're only keeping track of dates and not times in the database).

```
int subscriptionLengthInMonths = 6;
DateTime expiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(subscriptionLengthInMonths);
```